# What does the + subscript means in this situation?

Tags: estimation, notation

I am reading this paper "Model selection and estimation in regression with grouped variables," by Yuan and Lin. At some point, they show this expression

$$\beta_j = \left(1 - \frac{\lambda\sqrt{p_j}}{\|S_j\|}\right)_+ S_j$$

for the estimate $\beta_j$. I understand the expression inside the parentheses is a number, but what does the subscript + means in this situation?

Comment: The context should make it clear; but usually it means the positive part: that is, it's the larger of the value and zero.  With that in mind, re-read the paper and see whether that is consistent with what it's doing.  We can't tell you much unless you cite the paper accurately.

Comment: The paper should make it clear, but it's probably the so-called "relu" function: $(x)_+ = \max\{0,x\}.$